# Uploading fonts problems

Tags: font-face

Have a quick question about @font-face:

My CSS for the Birch Font doesn't seem to show up when I upload to the server and this is the CSS i'm using:

```
@font-face  {
font-family: "Birch Std";
src: url('fonts/BirchStd.otf');
}

.accordion .topicBar a  {
font-family:"Birch Std", Georgia, serif;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your format seems to be fine. Is the URL of BirchStd.otf correct? Is this up on the internet so we can look at it at all?

Comment: Hi Polly - Thanks for your response.  The odd thing for is when I work on it on my desktop computer here at work and test it out on the browser - it works.  But when I view it on my home computer or my iPhone the font does not show up.  But here is the site that I'm practising on and as you can see there is a substitute serif font that throws the formatting off a bit:  ' http://gis.urbansystems.ca/IDAP/home.html '                     Thanks for your help